# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error not throwing for unique index

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, soft-delete

`MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error` is not throwing every time userName Kim is created after the first.

```js
  // create the first 'Kim' with upsert
  const one = await Order.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userName: 'Kim' },
    { $set: { item: 'Flowers' } },
    { upsert: true, new: false }
  );

  // create duplicate- this doesn't throw a duplicate error
  const two = await Order.create({ userName: 'Kim' });

  // create duplicate- this throws a duplicate error
  const three = await Order.create({ userName: 'Kim' });
```

I would expect it two throw both times after the first since there is a `unique` index on `username`

```js
// Order Schema

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String,
    index: { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { deleted: false } },
  },
  item: { type: String },
});
```

This is what shows in the Mongo collection:

```json
{"_id":{"$oid":"62df67d456a37add52aba9c6"},"userName":"Kim","__v":{"$numberInt":"0"},"item":"Flowers"}

{"_id":{"$oid":"62df67d480a625d67e58461b"},"deleted":false,"userName":"Kim","__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

For some reason, `"deleted":false` isn't set when I use findAndUpdate to upsert.

**Full code**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoose_delete = require('mongoose-delete');

const connect = async (dsn) =>
  mongoose.connect(dsn, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    autoIndex: true,
  });

// Order Schema

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String,
    index: { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { deleted: false } },
  },
  item: { type: String },
});
orderSchema.plugin(mongoose_delete, {
  indexFields: ['deletedAt'],
  overrideMethods: 'all',
  validateBeforeDelete: false,
});

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
Order.createIndexes();

// Seeder
const seedLocalDatabase = async () => {
  await connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/newtestdb');
  await Order.deleteMany({});
};

(async () => {
  await seedLocalDatabase();

  const one = await Order.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userName: 'Kim' },
    { $set: { item: 'Flowers' } },
    { upsert: true, new: false }
  );

  // this doesn't throw a duplicate error
  const two = await Order.create({ userName: 'Kim' });

  // this throws a duplicate error
  const three = await Order.create({ userName: 'Kim' });

  mongoose.disconnect();
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue was caused by the `npm` module `mongoose-delete` which enables soft deleting. Soft deleting means that you can mark the documented as `deleted: true` instead of deleting the actual item.

I had set the index to:

```js
    index: { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { deleted: false } },
```

So it looks like if `deleted` wasn't set to `false`, mongoose ignored the index. It looks like upserting with `findAndModify` doesn't set delete with the `npm` module `mongoose-delete`, while `create` does.

Add `deleted: false`

```js
  const one = await Order.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userName: 'Kim' },
    { $set: { item: 'Flowers', deleted: false } },
    { upsert: true, new: false }
  );
```